# Django: Why is the Urls is different than what it should actually be?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am Django newbie. I am making a simple login custom system when I press sign-in button if the credential is correct it goes to the welcome page but the URL is `http://localhost:8000/login/` I was expecting `http://localhost:8000/welcome/` instead

[image: Pic of welcome page]
Here is my view.py code for login

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        username = request.POST['user']
        password = request.POST['psk']
        try:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'welcome.html')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or password didn\'t match.')

        except auth.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print("invalid user")

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

the URLs.py of the account app looks as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^index/$', home),
    url(r'^login/$', login),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout),
    url(r'^', custreg),
    
]
```

Please help me and let me know if you need anything else to answer the question

Comment: `url(r'^welcome/$', login)`, the path should be defined in your urlpatterns.

Comment: How would that solve the problem? That did not solve the problem @minglyu. I think I should also add a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do 3 things:

1. Create a `welcome` function inside `view.py` that returns the render output

```py
def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'welcome.html')
```

2. Add the following lines inside `yourapp/urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path

# add an entry to urlpatterns
urlpatterns=[
    path('welcome/', view.welcome, name='welcome'),
    # rest of the patterns
]
```

3. From the `login` function, instead of returning the html page, redirect the user to the `welcome` endpoint.

```py
# imports
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse

# inside your login function
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    # return render(request, 'welcome.html')
    return redirect(reverse('welcome'))
```

Restart your app after the changes.